# Connect to localhost from another computer in network

Tags: networking, wamp, wampserver

I have installed WAMP on one computer, and I want to connect to the phpmyadmin from another one. When I type, in a browser, 192.168.1.2/localhost i got following message:

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /localhost on this server.

I have changed this line in Apache:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all * from deny from all
</Directory>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try it without `localhost`. So if you access phpmyadmin on localhost as `localhost:8080/phpmyadmin` then you should do `192.168.1.2:8080/phpmyadmin`

**UPDATE:**

Change the file content

```
c:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf
```

to following:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I still got same message. (Windows firewall is turned off on both computers)

Comment: Could you try writing only `Allow from all` and remove the `* from deny from all` and then restart your server?

Comment: I have put * from deny from all to show what i have replaced (sorry for confusion)

Comment: Did you also change the phpmyadmin.conf?

Comment: I didn't know about that config file :O. phpmyadmin is now working :), but localhost is still forbidden? Any idea why?

Comment: Did you try to access `192.168.1.2:8080`?

Comment: I have tried, and I got following message: `This webpage is not available. The connection to 192.168.1.2 was interrupted.`

Answer (score 0):

I changed phpmyadmin.conf and Appache's httpd.conf to

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
```

and then restarted server. It worked quite well.

Thanks